# How to pick GIF image from UIImagepicker in swift 4?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, ios11

In my project trying to import GIF from UIImage picker. GIF image picked from gallery will certain actions like play and stop. Right now I can able to select GIF mage from gallery but result shows as image not gif image.

Can anyone help me out of this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this it will help you.

Step1: Create a global variable

```
var IMG:String?
```

Step2: put this function in your code.

```
    func getFileName(info: [String : Any]) -> String {

    if let assetPath = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL {
        let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [assetPath], options: nil)
        let asset = result.firstObject
        let fileName = asset?.value(forKey: "filename")
        let fileUrl = URL(string: fileName as! String)
        if let name = fileUrl?.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent {
            print(name)


   //let assetPath = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
            if (assetPath.absoluteString.hasSuffix("JPG")) {
                sonu = "JPG"
                print("JPG")
            }
            else if (assetPath.absoluteString.hasSuffix("PNG")) {
                sonu = "PNG"
                print("PNG")
            }
            else if (assetPath.absoluteString.hasSuffix("GIF")) {
                sonu = "GIF"
                print("GIF")
            }
            else {
                sonu = "Unknown"
                print("Unknown")
            }

            return name
        }
    }
    return ""

}
```

Step3: Set this code in your `ImagePickerController`

```
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    {
        imageview.image = image
        let IMG = getFileName(info: info)
        print(IMG)
        if IMG == "JPG"
        {
            imageDataForApi = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        }
        else if IMG == "GIF"
        {
            imageDataForApi = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0)
        }
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true) { () -> Void in

    }
```

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'sonu' How to clear this error!

Comment: @veerendra pratap singh Use of unresolved identifier 'sonu'

Comment: @BizDev replace with IMG in first step we create a global variable we will use it .